# Shove table data as binary into UDF

Tags: apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF defined like so:

```
def my_function(input: Array[Byte])
```

and I want to call it in spark SQL, so i'm trying

```
SELECT my_function(binary(CONCAT(*))) FROM table;
```

but I don't think this is working. To my understanding, `select *` will return `Array[Row]`, and then calling the native function `binary` will serialize that. Will that convert `Array[Row]` to `Array[Byte]`? Not sure how to call this udf via sql

Answer (score 0):

We have to register the function and then we can use the UDF

ie

spark.udf.register(funname and definition )

you can explore more on [link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html)

Comment: It's already registered, and I know that because spark doesn't complain that it isn't. I'm just trying to call it with the right input

Comment: We have to register the UDF every time.